# PUT and DELETE requests unsuccessful on PHP REST API, but POST and GET are fine

Tags: php, rest, put, slim, http-delete

I've got a slimPHP REST API built. Here's what I have for headers:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true"); 
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, accept');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
```

Yet when I try a cross-domain PUT or DELETE request, all I get is (sample domains):

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.example.com/api/x.
Origin http://www.example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Any idea why this is happening if Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set to * ?

Comment: What kind of server are you running it on?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Slim Framework Documentation](http://docs.slimframework.com/#PUT-Routes):

> Unfortunately, modern browsers do not provide native support for HTTP PUT requests. To work around this limitation, ensure your HTML form’s method attribute is “post”, then add a method override parameter to your HTML form like this:
>
> ```
>     <form action="/books/1" method="post">
>         ... other form fields here...
>         <input type="hidden" name="_METHOD" value="PUT"/>
>         <input type="submit" value="Update Book"/>
>     </form>
> ```
>
> If you are using Backbone.js or a command-line HTTP client, you may also override the HTTP method by using the X-HTTP-Method-Override header.

You can use any request type you would like (including custom ones like `foo`), but GET and POST are the only ones natively supported by modern browsers.